# Can't load account on IBM's qiskit

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

The command load account keeps giving the warning that it can't find a QConfig file. A search for the error message brings me to an [answered question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4838/how-to-set-up-qconfig-py-and-where-is-the-file). However, this solution also doesn't work, producing the same error:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Hi, what qiskit version are you using?

Comment: Version 0.17.0.

Comment: Try regenerating your token and going through the save and load process again. Before saving the new token, make sure to run `IBMQ.delete_account()` to remove the old token, and any older credentials in general that may still be present. If the save goes through, try running `IBMQ.stored_account()` as well to see if it can find the saved credentials that way.

Comment: The issue is fixed, i just needed to run the command line as adm.